# Hide/filter features from Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Setup: 
OpenLayers 3

Description: 
I have a map and I need to draw GPS points (10000+) to the map  points have extra attributes on them (id, datetime, name etc.). I also have to draw path between those points. I now have two layers, one with the features and one with the line drawn from the GPS points. I need to filter (hide) the points and the line by the time attribute.

What is the fastest way to filter (hide) features (10000+) from a layer?

Comment: For your first question: it is indeed a smart choice to store those data in separate layers. I unfortunately cannot help you evaluating the solution now, however some tips: for this kind of big data (in web mapping terms), use the WebGL renderer. For the lines, use an `ImageVector` source, while for filtering, use a style function. There are many talented developers in this forum, who can help you further, I hope you get an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize features in layers and remove layers from map if needed. If you store the layer in a variable, you can also readd it.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#removeLayer